# VS Code API: How do I retrieve ExtensionContext outside of extension.ts?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using VS Code API's ExtensionContext.globalState() to count the number of the times the sidebar of our extension has been opened. This is inside a command a handler in extension.ts and it counts the number of opens on local storage as expected.

I want to retrieve that count on a .js file where we are using JQuery to append components to the UI of the sidebar. However, I don't know how to retrieve ExtensionContext.globalState outisde of extension.ts

This is how I'm getting and updating the value of the count on extension.ts

```
    const retrievedOpeningCountValue = context.globalState.get<Number>("sidebarOpeningCount");
    // If show hasn't been called yet, retrieve 0, then increase it to 1 to store such value
    let retrievedValue = retrievedOpeningCountValue?.valueOf() || 0;
    let increasedValue = retrievedValue + 1;
    context.globalState.update("sidebarOpeningCount", increasedValue);
```

And then I need to retrieve that number on my JQuery file. I can't do `import * as vscode from "vscode";` because it't not a TS file. Even if it was, `context: vscode.ExtensionContext` can only be passed as a parameter to the activate function on extension.ts.

But basically I wanna do something like `const retrievedOpeningCountValue = context.globalState.get<Number>("sidebarOpeningCount");`on a js file. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply assign `context` to some global / shared resource, and import it on any other `.js`/`.ts` file.

Something like:

extension.ts

```js
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    Container.context = context;
```

container.ts

```js
import { ExtensionContext } from "vscode";

export class Container {
    private static _extContext: ExtensionContext;
  
    public static get context(): ExtensionContext {
      return this._extContext;
    }
  
    public static set context(ec: ExtensionContext) {
      this._extContext = ec;
    }
  }
```

yourotherfile.ts

```js
import { Container } from "../container";

...
const retrievedOpeningCountValue = Container.context.globalState.get<Number>("sidebarOpeningCount");
```